# How to open a .xsd file in Visual Studio Professional 2022 without using XML Schema Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, visual-studio-2022

I want to open the .xsd file as a normal file. You can easily do this in Visual Studio Code, it opens normally. BUT! When you open a .xsd file in Visual studio professional, it opens this window saying "visualize nodes in your XML schema set by dragging them from the XML Schema Explorer onto the design surface". I just want to edit the file normally without the XML Schema Explorer.

Comment: Don't you have a "right clic -> open with" option on the file ? Could you share a screenshot ?